# How to change a Prism module in runtime

Tags: .net, wpf, prism

How to change modules in run time? I have ribbon menu with commands binded. On menu item click I want change modules on form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK Prism module is simply an assembly loaded in the common Application Domain so unloading of a particular assembly is not possible (.NET Framework limitation).

PS:
Why Prism is not considered loading a module into the separate AppDomain as an option, in this way all modules would be pretty good isolated and `Load/Unload` will be available as well. I believe this would be a great benefit for Enterprise solutions with critical priority requirements for reliability since when multiple assemblies loaded into the same AppDomain - error in one assembly potentially could crash entire AppDomain, from my standpoint this is unacceptable for robust and reliable applications. Nice to have "Module per Assembly" by default, but additional option "Module per AppDomain" would be great. Perhaps I missed something important? Would be interesting know reasons why Module per assembly but not per AppDomain.